# Most stable version to work with in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop

I wanted to know the most stable version of Hadoop 2.x until now.

I saw in some forums that Hadoop 2.2 and 2.4 are kind of stable, but I need more advice.

Added to this, Is it possible to install Hadoop 2.x, Eclipse Europa and Cygwin in Windows 7 and develop Hadoop applications with eclipse Europa? I've been searching for a tutorial but I found solutions only for Hadoop 1.x? Is it the same thing?

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: 2.6 is the most recent *stable* release of Apache Hadoop: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/ -- as someone who is involved in multiple hadoop clusters, the new versions of Hadoop as they come up are very "stable"

Comment: Thank you so much @Donald Miner for the clarification.

Comment: @Donald Miner can you help me again? Thank you.